# Creating a Javascript tree out of array of strings

Tags: javascript, json, tree

Given an array of an array of strings like such:

```
incoming = [["1","A","C","3"],
            ["2","A","C","1"],
            ["1","B","D","3"],
            ["2","B","D","4"],
            ["2","B","D","5"]];
```

How do I convert it to a json object like this:

```
[
  { "1": [
         { "A": [
                 { "C": ["3"] 
                 }
              ]
         },
         { "B": [
                 { "D": ["3"] 
                 }
              ]
         }
       ]
   },
   { "2": [
         { "A": [
                 { "C": ["1"] 
                 }
              ]
         },
         { "B": [
                 { "D": ["4","5"] 
                 }
              ]
         }
       ]
   }
]
```

I've looked at several answers to related questions, but can't figure out how to map them to this particular requirement.

In PHP it would be very simple.

```
foreach (incoming AS inc)
{
    output[inc[0]][inc[1]][inc[2]][inc[3]] = "x"; 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You PHP wouldn't work as you suggest, as you would simply get a multi-dimensional array rather than an array of object with nested arrays of objects.

Comment: ^ But also there's nothing dynamic about that PHP solution... I guess that's the point of this question otherwise you can just do the same in JS if you know there's always 4 items.

Comment: Are you sure that's the data structure you want? All of your objects only have one property. Are you sure you want arrays of one-property objects, and not objects with multiple properties corresponding to the strings?

Comment: Thank you all for your input. My real input is an array of arrays. Each 2nd level array has four properties: 'Stage', 'Building', 'Floor', and 'Phase. These are the four ID values you see. I'm going to rethink how to represent these both on the server (php) and in the client (Javascript). I will edit this question when it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question is not formulated very well. Maybe you want:

```
var incoming = [['1', 'A', 'C', '3'], ['2', 'A', 'C', '1'], ['1', 'B', 'D', '3'], ['2', 'B', 'D', '4'], ['2', 'B', 'D', '5']];
var obj = {}, propNames = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4', 'prop5'];
for(var i in incoming){
   obj[propNames[i]] = incoming[i];
}
```

Take note, however, that you cannot run a `for in` loop on `.getElementsByTagName()` or `.getElementsByName()` with earlier versions of IE. If your getting your information based on that your code might look like:

```
var incoming = [['1', 'A', 'C', '3'], ['2', 'A', 'C', '1'], ['1', 'B', 'D', '3'], ['2', 'B', 'D', '4'], ['2', 'B', 'D', '5']];
var obj = {}, propNames = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4', 'prop5'];
for(var i=0,l=incoming.length; i>l; i++){
    obj[propNames[i]] = incoming[i];
}
```

Notice that `arrayName[increment]` or `objectName[property]` gets a value in JavaScript equivalent to the `$value` variable in PHP's `foreach($whatever as $value)`. Of course, all I did is assign each array to obj.prop1 and so on. It would not create the structure you shown. That would require that every property of your JavaScript Object have a different name.

To replicate bottom PHP code, in JavaScript it could look like:

```
var output = {};
for(var i in incoming){
  var inc = incoming[i];
  output[inc[0]][inc[1]][inc[2]][inc[3]] = 'x';
}
```

Note that my last snippet of code above, and your last snippet make no sense. This would not work in PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: I realized my code snipped did not work. Thank you for your assistance. I've re-factored my code so I'm not using this style, but your answer did get me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into two steps,

Step 1, convert the array into an *Object* tree

```
var incoming = [["1","A","C","3"], ["2","A","C","1"], ["1","B","D","3"],
                ["2","B","D","4"], ["2","B","D","5"]];

var i, j, o = {}, c, k;

for (i = 0; i < incoming.length; ++i) {
    c = o;
    for (j = 0; j < incoming[i].length; ++j) {
        k = incoming[i][j];
        if (!c[k]) c[k] = {};
        c = c[k];
    }
}
```

Now `o` looks like what you want, except it isn't arrayed as you desire, so needs a little more work.
Step 2, re-create the *Object* tree by keys=>arrays, using recursion

```
function recurseKeys(o) {
    var arr = [],
        k = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o),
        i, c;
    for (i = 0; i < k.length; ++i) {
        if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o[k[i]]).length)
            c = {}, c[k[i]] = recurseKeys(o[k[i]]);
        else
            c = k[i];
        arr.push(c);
    }
    return arr;
}

o = recurseKeys(o);
```

Now `o` should have the structure you want, so JSON-ify it

```
JSON.stringify(o);
// "[{"1":[{"A":[{"C":["3"]}]},{"B":[{"D":["3"]}]}]},{"2":[{"A":[{"C":["1"]}]},{"B":[{"D":["4","5"]}]}]}]"
```